How to turn off application crash automatic reporting
I want to know how to turn off the 'automatically send app crash info to the developer' option so that I can see the window appear when an application crashes.
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 - I'm a bit of a linux newb.
I installed Shutter just now from the command line (sudo apt install shutter) and then started it from the Show Apps menu.  It promptly crashed and popped up a 'do you want to send crash data' window.  There was an option to do this always.  So I clicked it.  And a 'restart the app' option, which I also clicked.  Presumably it sent its message and then attempted to restart but I didn't see anything.  I'm guessing that Shutter crashed a second time.  I waited a while and tried running it again and nothing appeared.  So I uninstalled it from the command line (sudo apt install shutter).  I found a similar app so I  installed that (sudo apt install flameshot).  When I tried starting it from Show Apps nothing appeared.  I'm guessing it also crashed and automatically fired off a report.  I'd like to know when this happens so I want to turn off the automatic reporting so I can at least know it crashed before I send the report.  How do I do this?
Also, any idea how I find out what's going wrong?

Try running the application from a command line add add the following 'appname 2>&1' If it crashes all data sent to stdout and stderr goes to the terminal.

To control the bug reporting see the following link: - https://vitux.com/how-to-disable-enable-automatic-error-reporting-in-ubuntu/
